# On Click add Class to First <td> in Row and corresponding <th> in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table which has clickable `<td>`'s.

When I click a Cell in the table I want to add a class to

- The first `<td>` in the row I clicked on
- The `<th>` which corresponds to the column that the row is in

Essentially I am trying to show which `<td>` is clicked on visually.

I can figure out how to add a class to the first `<td>` in the row but it adds them to it all and not just the one I am in. I cannot figure out how to add it to the `<th>`

Looking for some advice on how to do this in Jquery. My incomplete code is:

```
//Adding Class Needed
$('.table-bordered tr td').on('click',function(){
    //Add Class to First TD in ROW
        $("tr td:nth-child(1)").addClass('superStyle');
    //Add Class to Header <th> Cell above
    });
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/L8s5X/

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/L8s5X/12/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){
    //Hover and click colors
    var table = $('table').on('click', 'td', function(){
        $('.table-bordered tr td').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    //Adding Class Needed
    $(table).find('tr td').on('click',function(){
        //Add Class to First TD in ROW
        table.find('.superStyle').removeClass('superStyle');
        $(this).closest('tr').find("td:nth-child(1)").addClass('superStyle');
        //Add Class to Header <th> Cell above
        table.find('thead th').eq($(this).index()).addClass('superStyle')
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/54MvV/)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is, your selector is told to do that.

You need to create the selector within the context of the click

```
    $(this).parent().find('td:nth-child(1)').addClass('superStyle');
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/L8s5X/7/

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L8s5X/9/)

```
$('.table-bordered tr td').on('click', function () {
        var $table = $(this).closest('table'),
              $tds = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
        $table.find('.superStyle').removeClass('superStyle');
        //Add Class to First TD in ROW
        $tds.eq(0).addClass('superStyle');
        //Add Class to Header <th> Cell above
        var index = $tds.index(this);
        $table.find('th').eq(index).addClass('superStyle');
    });
```

Comment: THanks, but this does not do 2 things...1) It does not highlight the <th> above the td I clicked. 2) My fault, I should of wrote this but I want it to toggle the class. So if I click on another TD it should remove it from the one I just clicked on

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to work as desired:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8s5X/11/)

```
// save elements before binding the event handler, to save processing time
var $table = $('table'),
    $headings = $table.find('thead th'),
    $fields = $table.find('td');

$table.on('click', 'td', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        index = $this.index();

    $fields.removeClass('active');
    $this.parent().children(':first-child').addClass('active');

    $headings.removeClass('superStyle').eq(index).addClass('superStyle');
});
```